# Redirect when authorization fails

Tags: java, java-web-start

I have a webstart app which requires the user to authorize to run.  Circumstances in the website in which the app is deployed make it necessary that the user does not hit refresh.

So, the problem is, if they decline authorization, hitting refresh won't make it show up.

What I'd like is a way to detect if the app crashed, so that I can redirect the users to a different page.

OR

The ability to give the user the option to re-show the authorization prompt without calling a page refresh.

A note:  I know these restrictions are kind of weird, but that is out of my control, nor was it my idea.  Any help is much appreciated!

**[edit]**

Some clarifications:
What happens when the user hits refresh, is they get redirected to an error page.  This app is being used in a survey, though it is optional, I need a way to recover gracefully if the user denies the certificate.

Also, this is the certificate for the signed jar, not something like an https connection or the site log in.

Comment: This sounds like a security nightmare waiting to happen

Answer (score 0):

Your question is lacking some details but here is a brain dump of what you might be able to do.

The best bet is to ensure that a authentication failure (or decline to authn) causes the session to be destroyed. Then each time they go to the page it will look like a fresh run for both the server and the client and thus it will re prompt them for their creds. Also you could make sure that an auth failure simply shows the login page again with a message indicating that the last logic failed.

Comment: I added some more detail to the original post;  I hope that helps some.  The really annoying thing, is it is absolutely important the session be preserved.  Also, the prompt isn't security credentials of the client;  but rather the client is prompted to authorize the jar file before it can run (needs extended privileges on their system).  If there is a way to catch an event when they decline, and do something in javascript, that would be magnificent.

Comment: Ahh,well then I am afraid I don't know the answer to that. I believe that action is handled as part of the native browser security model through its Java plugin and thus outside of what you have to work with in javascript, but I could be wrong.